# Appirater - after tap nothing happens

Tags: ios, app-store, appirater

I'm using Appirater for rating my app. Everything is fine, alert shows me message with buttons. But when I tap on button "Rate my app" there's no answer Appirater my app. Alert just disappeared. There's my code in my app delegate:

```
[Appirater setAppId:@"579808129"];
[Appirater setDaysUntilPrompt:0];
[Appirater setUsesUntilPrompt:2];
[Appirater setTimeBeforeReminding:2];
[Appirater setDebug:YES];
[Appirater appLaunched:YES];
```

Thx for reply.

Comment: Is there any way that Appirater works fine but there's thing of GUI? When I'm starting app I'm downloading some data from web API, and then  reloading tableview. Could it be a problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm using slide menu in my application. And there's problem because I have controller which is support for slide menu like rootViewController, so when I load appirater controller it's controller with menu. So I'm going to change somehow appirater get-root-controller function. Thx for all guys! ;)

Comment: Can you improve the answer by writing some code for it.. faceing same probelm

Answer (score 3):

Appirater will not send you to the app store on the simulator unless you are on ios6+. Are you testing on either the ios6+ simulator OR an actual device?

Comment: I'm testing it on real device with iOS 6. Thx for interest.

Comment: ah ok. I would suggest putting a break point in the rateApp method of the Appirater class to see what's going on.

Comment: I pretty much have the exact code you posted except I have an additional: [Appirater appEnteredForeground:YES];  in the appdelegate's - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application method. Works perfectly.

Comment: I have the same code in applicationWillEnterForeground. So when I set the breakpoint in Appirater in RateApp method everything goes fine. I have valid appId, condition respondsToSelector with appiraterWillPresentModalView selector is equal NO, then there's presentViewController with storeViewController.

Comment: looking at appirater's code, my next guess would be there's an issue getting the rootViewController. [self getRootViewController] might be returning nil so its not able to present the store view controller. How are you setting up your root vc?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you set your delegate and also subscribe to the delegate from your class with

```
<@interface MyAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, AppiraterDelegate>{


[Appirater setDelegate:self];
[Appirater setAppId:APPIRATER_APP_ID_HERE];
[Appirater setDaysUntilPrompt:1];
[Appirater setUsesUntilPrompt:10];
[Appirater setSignificantEventsUntilPrompt:-1];
[Appirater setTimeBeforeReminding:2];
[Appirater appLaunched:YES];
[Appirater setDebug:YES];
```

Comment: Did you do all the requirements in the getting started section @ https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater ?

Comment: Add perhaps add the delegate to your class with @interface MyAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, AppiraterDelegate>{

Comment: I have and I did all the requirements.

Comment: I had to set delegate first, as in this example, that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to appirater.h

```
    #define APPIRATER_DEBUG YES
```

You could see the appirater popup on simulator. But you should use device for rating the app.

Comment: The problem is I'll get the popup overtime when I startup application. It will show the popup everytime when I call     [Appirater userDidSignificantEvent:YES]; if the DEBUG is YES.